# Setting up regex-style rewrite rules within Drupal?

Tags: 7, redirection, path-aliases, uri

I have a couple of legacy rewrite rule redirects that I've traditionally put in .htaccess. For instance, paths are of the format:

`story/[story:title]`

And paths like:

`story/[story:nid]`

redirect to that.

Is there any way of setting up regex-matching redirects within Drupal? I could always do it in .htaccess, but that would get overwritten on the next Drupal core update. Further, it seems that Boost is nerfing any redirect I put in .htaccess -- the above hasn't worked since I installed its redirect rules.

Thanks!

Comment: You can move your rewrite rules to apache configuration files. To be safe just add `include your_custom_rules.conf` in your main configuration file and add rules to that custom file so that it never gets overwritten.

Comment: @2-Stroker That's not a bad idea. Still wouldn't solve the issue of Boost's rewrite rules taking precedence over mine, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you are familiar with PHP and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), you could theoretically install Drupal [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and write custom rules using PHP to redirect pages inside Drupal without touching .htaccess file.

Comment: I guess that's one way to go about it. Bit heavy, though -- I don't have Rules enabled already, and to do so for simple redirects seems a bit much.

Comment: You can use `hook_init()` inside modules if you are not ok with using a module just for one purpose.

Comment: @2-Stroker -- Can you explain that a bit further?

Comment: I guess @2-Stroker meant that you write a custom module with only hook_init() and then get current url using drupal_get_destination() and then write custom PHP code to rewrite url and then use drupal_goto() to redirect page to new url.  I am not sure if hook_init() is the best place to write this, but it might work as well.

Comment: hook_boot is the better for redirects. See shurly module for an example.

Comment: Accepting because it's most in the spirit of the original question. That said, I'd argue that my answer is lighter and easier to maintain/version control if you have access to the virtualhost config.

Answer (score 1):

It just dawned on me that you don't *need* to define Rewrite Rules in .htaccess — if the goal is to prevent Drush from nuking custom rewrites during Drupal core updates, it makes **way** more sense to just put them straight into the httpd.conf VirtualHost directive (If you have access to that).

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/120488/redirect-url-within-apache-virtualhost

Leaving question open in case somebody has a better solution more applicable to a broader cross-section of the community (I.e., users on shared hosting without access to .conf files).